# GWT SoundManager 2 play() throw exception

Tags: java, gwt, audio, soundmanager2

I just tried to use GWT-SoundManager2 to make some noise.
I have just tried a simple code as the following:

```
SoundManager sm;
String SS = "soundId"
sm = SoundManager.quickStart();
sm.createSound(SS, "/sounds/mysound.wav");
sm.play(SS);
```

but it throws the exception:

Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object [object Object] has no method 'toLowerCase'
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)

However, if I change to the following, it will work:

```
SoundManager sm;
String SS = "soundId"
sm = SoundManager.quickStart();
sm.play(SS, "/sounds/mysound.wav");
```

I want to use CreateSound because I want to preload the audio first. Is there anything I did wrong there in the first block of codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is anything wrong with your code. The only thing that might be happening is SoundManager might not be fully loaded prior to your call to createSound().

Ideally you call quickStart() and sometime after you invoke functions such as play or create sound on your soundManager instance. You can be notified when SoundManager is ready by using the onReady() function to fire a callback.

If you're still having this problem please open an issue on the github page. There's also a newly created example project which can be found at https://github.com/rcaloras/gwt-soundmanager2-example.